# Using PHPmyadmin Query doesn`t join tables automatically

Tags: user-interface, phpmyadmin, join

I have got a problem with a query over 2 tables that are connected to each other with a foreign key constraint.
I have got students und classes with a n:1 relationship.
When I use the Gui-Query in phpmyadmin, the query doesn`t join the tables via Primary and referenced key like it is said in all the internet tutorials.
If I use direct sql statements everything works.

SELECT class.cid, class.value, students.name FROM class, students WHERE
class.cid=students.cid;

Here are the pricture:

https://sites.google.com/site/bildungscenterunterlagen/mysql

(Unfortunately I am not able to embed the pictures directly in my question)

Thanks a lot
fhs14647

Comment: I refer to this web tutorial, where the multi table query is described:
http://www.packtpub.com/article/multi-table-query-generator-using-phpmyadmin-mysql

In the end an automatic inner join is made. What somehow I don`t manage this automatic innerjoin.

Thanks a lot
fhs14647

Comment: ... and I am using XAMPP Version 4.2.3

Comment: ..iis there really noone who knows the solution...
It would be very important for me.
Thanks a lot
fhs14647